# Why String.contains with empty String returns true?

Tags: java, string

When i work with my code i found this,

```
 String myString1="foo";
 String myString2="";
          if(myString1.contains(myString2)){
              System.out.println("Am here");
          }
          else{
              System.out.println("Am not here");
          }
```

it print always `Am here` why?
Please any one help me to find this.

Comment: it's true, myString1 contains "". but is not equal "".

Answer (score 7):

It is the same principle that the Empty Set is a subset of every possible set.

Comment: But is the empty set a subset of the empty set? Argh!!!

Comment: All sets are subsets of themselves, but not proper subsets.

Comment: @MattCoubrough Yes it is. Think of a subset this way "Can I subtract this?" and then think of the empty set or `String.Empty` in this case, as 0. You can subtract 0 from anything.